# Unable to verify x-slack-signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, slack, slack-api

I've been having a slack app for a few years already. It was used exclusively in only one workspace.
On receiving a slack command I run a regular auth check as it described in [slack API](https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack).

My code:

```
const requestSignatureHeader = req.headers["x-slack-signature"] as string;
const requestTimestamp = req.headers["x-slack-request-timestamp"];
const hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", this.signingSecret);
const [version, requestSignature] = requestSignatureHeader.split("=");
const rawBody = stringify(req.body)
        .replace(/\+/g, "%2B")
        .replace(/%20/g, "+")
        .replace(/!/g, "%21")
        .replace(/'/g, "%27")
        .replace(/:/g, "%3A")
        .replace(/,/g, "%2C")
        .replace(/@/g, "%40")
        .replace(/\//g, "%2F");
const stringToSign = `${version}:${requestTimestamp}:${rawBody}`;
hmac.update(stringToSign);
const calculatedSignature = hmac.digest("hex");
const isValid = requestSignature === calculatedSignature;
```

It was working correctly until a few weeks ago we've moved to the enterprise workspace (it maybe just a coincidence though).

Right now `x-slack-signature` is always different from the calculated value. I've checked multiple times: `signing secret` is the same that specified in app's settings. Any ideas what could be the problem?